# Relationship (schema) for Accounts, Customers, Partners

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

I recently started developing for Odoo and have created a few modules, but I'm having difficulty figuring out the structure for accounts, customers, and partners.

I'm trying to adapt one of our current applications in which it's Accounts>Customers> and Accounts>Billing accounts. I basically what to add a tab to the customer creation view called billing accounts. Problem is I can't figure out what is tied to what. It looks like it's Partners>Accounts>Customers or Sales>Accounts>Customers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a bank account (i.e. your customer or partner's bank account), I believe the relation is res_partner_bank (many2one relation).

If you are talking about another concept, please clarify what you mean by billing account (invoicing, pur accounting, etc...) in order to understand the context.

As a sidenote, every entity (person/company) is stored in res_partner. You then have a boolean flag specifying whether the entity is a customer and/or a partner
and/or a company (so in short partner_id is usually the relationship key).

Comment: Let me clarify a bit. In our current system we have account as grandparent object with parent companies and they child billing accounts. Account has all the the company information and it is very similar to Customers in Odoo. So if you were looking at an open customer in Odoo, what I'm looking to add is a tab with all the child locations as well as the billing account information for them. It would be Account (Customer)>Child Customers>Billing Accounts or similar.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit. In our current system we have account as grandparent object with parent companies and they child billing accounts. Account has all the the company information and it is very similar to Customers in Odoo. So if you were looking at an open customer in Odoo, what I'm looking to add is a tab with all the child locations as well as the billing account information for them. It would be Account (Customer)>Child Customers>Billing Accounts or similar.